# How to hide/display a set of HTML table rows when clicking on some other sibling table row?

Tags: html, tablerow

I've been looking around, finding some solutions and trying to apply them, with little luck.

I am putting together an HTML file that displays test results.
Test results are shown in rows:

```
<tr>
    <th class="test_name_row" colspan="5">Test: spc-aes-gcm-decrypt</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="subtest_name_col">Subtest 1</td>
    <td class="neutral_metric">2880</td>
    <td class="good_metric">2880</td>
    <td class="neutral_metric">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="subtest_name_col">Subtest 2</td>
    <td class="neutral_metric">2880</td>
    <td class="good_metric">2880</td>
    <td class="neutral_metric">0</td>
</tr>
```

The behavior I'm looking for is the following:
If the user clicks on the 'test_name_row', the two table rows beneath will collapse / unfold, hopefully with some sleek animation.

What's the best strategy to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:**

HTML

```
        <tr>
            <th class="test_name_row" colspan="5" onclick="hideShow()">Test: spc-aes-gcm-decrypt</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row1">
            <td class="subtest_name_col">Subtest 1</td>
            <td class="neutral_metric">2880</td>
            <td class="good_metric">2880</td>
            <td class="neutral_metric">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2">
            <td class="subtest_name_col">Subtest 2</td>
            <td class="neutral_metric">2880</td>
            <td class="good_metric">2880</td>
            <td class="neutral_metric">0</td>
        </tr>
```

Javascript

```
        var hidden = false;
        function hideShow() {
            if (hidden == true) {
                //show
                document.getElementById("row1").classList.remove("hidden");
                document.getElementById("row2").classList.remove("hidden");
                document.getElementById("row1").classList.add("visible");
                document.getElementById("row2").classList.add("visible");
                hidden = false;
            } else {
                //hide
                document.getElementById("row1").classList.add("hidden");
                document.getElementById("row2").classList.add("hidden");
                document.getElementById("row1").classList.remove("visible");
                document.getElementById("row2").classList.remove("visible");
                hidden = true;
            }
        }
```

CSS

```
        .hidden {
            opacity: 0;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }
        .visible {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }
```

If you don't want to have animation, you can remove those classes (from both CSS and JS) and just use

```
.style.display = "none"
```

in javascript.

**Same as a snippet:**

```js
var hidden = false;
function hideShow() {
    if (hidden == true) {
        //show
        document.getElementById("row1").classList.remove("hidden");
        document.getElementById("row2").classList.remove("hidden");
        document.getElementById("row1").classList.add("visible");
        document.getElementById("row2").classList.add("visible");
        hidden = false;
    } else {
        //hide
        document.getElementById("row1").classList.add("hidden");
        document.getElementById("row2").classList.add("hidden");
        document.getElementById("row1").classList.remove("visible");
        document.getElementById("row2").classList.remove("visible");
        hidden = true;
    }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
        <th class="test_name_row" colspan="5" onclick="hideShow()">Test: spc-aes-gcm-decrypt</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td class="subtest_name_col">Subtest 1</td>
        <td class="neutral_metric">2880</td>
        <td class="good_metric">2880</td>
        <td class="neutral_metric">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td class="subtest_name_col">Subtest 2</td>
        <td class="neutral_metric">2880</td>
        <td class="good_metric">2880</td>
        <td class="neutral_metric">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: added one missing row